# How to exit from an infinite loop in c without closing command prompt?

Tags: c, linux

When run code in command prompt if the code display an infinite loop how to exit from this loop without exiting window.

Comment: Did you try the break key?

Comment: Please tell us what key combination you are using that causes the "command prompt" to close? Are you using an IDE by any chance?

Comment: Type Control-C.

Comment: Cntrl + C (Break), Cntrl + \ (Abort) try it